# Getting the path to a file in a folder and reading the file

Tags: c#

I have a test project in a visual studio solution which has a folder named Files. There are files
in this folder and I want to read one of the files.

```
        string fileName = @"\Files\Tester.xlsx";
        string fullPath;
        fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);

        var content = File.OpenRead(fullPath);
```

This is what I kept getting.

```
        System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the 
        path 'C:\Files\Tester.xlsx'.'
```

It seems like it is looking at C:\Files which does not exist.

Comment: You're potentially missing a full stop at the beginning of the path: string fileName = @".\Files\Tester.xlsx";

Comment: The dot did not help. It is looking at the bin folder which is wrong. The file does not exist in the bin folder

Comment: Two options I'd recommend: Either include the full path to the file, or include the files as content in the project to they're copied to the output folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are entering a *relative* path, relative here means relative to where the executable is running (the bin folder), not relative to your .sln file.  Either supply an absolute path, move your Files folder to the bin folder, or use "..\" to get to the folder that had your parent file (i.e. if your file structure is C:\Code\Solution\Project\bin the path to Files is C:\Code\Solution\Files then ..\..\..\Files\Tester.xls should do).